# Why is MAIL unset in graphical environments?

Tags: bash, email

I get new-mail notifications when running `bash` interactively on Linux console but I don't get them on `xterm` or `konsole`.

The environment variable `MAIL` is set to `/var/mail/USER` upon logging in on the console but it's empty on `xterm` and `konsole`.

Also, `MAIL` is not mentioned in any of `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, nor is it printed by `grep -r MAIL= /etc`.

Why is it unset in the graphical environment? (Debian 7.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program `login` sets the `MAIL` environmental variable when you login to a Linux virtual console.

From the `login(1)` manpage:

> The value for $HOME, $USER, $SHELL, $PATH, $LOGNAME, and $MAIL are set  according  to  the appropriate fields in the password entry.

`login` is the program used to start a session when you login to a Linux virtual console. It prompts you for a username and password, sets some basic environmental variables, and starts a shell.

If you're using a graphical login manager (e.g. one supplied with Gnome or KDE) instead of `login`, the `MAIL` environmental variable may not be set.

Bash usually only gives mail notifications when it is being used as a login shell. Even if the `MAIL` environmental variable is set, a normal interactive instance of `bash` within `xterm` or `konsole` will not display a mail notification.

You can run `bash` with the `-l` flag to force it to behave like a login shell. You can pass `xterm` the `-ls` flag to make it start your shell as a login shell.

Comment: `xterm -ls` and `bash -l` dont' change this behavior here. But if I set `MAIL=/var/mail/$USER` I get notifications in `konsole`. Maybe I should take a look at `kdm`.